# How to create a "background timer" on Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework, countdowntimer

I am struggling to create (and to find similar examples) of what I understand as a "background timer" on Robot Framework.
My scenario is:
I have a Test Case to Execute, and at a certain point I give one input to my system. Then I need to keep testing other functionalities on the way, but after 30 min from that initial input, check if the expected outcome is happening or not.

For example:

```
Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    My_Keyword
#This keyword should trigger the system timer.

Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Another_Keyword
#This one does not relate with the timer but must also be executed.

Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    My_Third_Keyword
#Same for this one.

Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Check_Timer_Result
#This one shall see if the inputs from the first keyword are actually having effect.
```

Since I know the Keyword "Sleep" will pause the execution and wait, I have been think about using some logic + [BultIn Get Time keyword](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Time). But wondering if this is the most efficient way.

Comment: What would do here is actually multithreading, start a thread with the timer and let it monitor its exhaustion (as the execution may be in a totally different case, or a suite at that point). That would be quite complicated though, thus just a comment - a food for thought on what to research...

Comment: I usually use this: Get the current time and add 30 minutes. After your keywords, you can calculate how long you need to sleep until 30 minutes are passed.